# Laravel: whereBetween to accept the first date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Scenario:

The `startdate` and `enddata` in the database is `2015-07-20` and `2015-07-30` respectively and the query that works properly is,

```
Model::whereBetween('startdate',array('2015-07-30','2015-08-10'))->get();
```

The query return 1 record from the table which is the expected result. Now what I expect is a slight change. The query should not retrieve the record by considering the date `2015-07-30` does not fall in between `2015-07-30`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**whereBetween** is inclusive. In order to exclude one of the edges you'll need to build a between query manually:

```
Model::where('startdate', '>', '2015-07-30')->where('startdate', '<=', '2015-08-10')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy Solution

```
Model::whereBetween(DB::raw('date(startdate)'),array('2015-07-30','2015-08-10'))->get();
```